# How can I get selected item in UITableView

Tags: uitableview, swift3, selected

How can I get selected item from `UITableView` in Swift3?
I try this way:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    //do something
}
```

but it isn't work for me.

Comment: Can you show us what you are trying to select? Are you trying to pass data to a different view controller?

Comment: I think you didn't set the `delegate` of `tableView`.

Comment: @Sachin you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to set `@IBOutlet` to the `tableView` in your `ViewController` and set as it's `delegate` and `dataSourc`e to you can see the data an respond to changes in the `tableView` ;

```
class YourViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
    }
```

After

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
    }
```

You can get selected cell.
Ty.

Comment: Thanks, for solution.